# Jupyter notebook won't load in browser automatically

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, jupyter

When I type `jupyter-notebook` or `jupyter-lab` in the command prompt on Ubuntu 20, a window opens in Firefox with the message "Access to the file was denied". If I copy the link that is generated in the terminal, I can open the notebook but I would rather it opens automatically like it always has on every other system I have installed Jupyter via Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

It was as easy as removing Firefox through the Software Manager then reinstalling it via the command line `sudo apt install firefox`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).